# search in multilevel linked lists in Pascal

Tags: data-structures, pascal, singly-linked-list

So in this program we are asked to create a database for a university, the university is divided into  faculties and each faculty is divided into departments, similarly, each department is divided into courses (specialities) and each course is divided into grades, and each grade has a list of students. I implemented this using linked  lists, after the  user fills the database, they get some options to interact with the database such as adding and removing students, etc. But, when I try to search for a student in the database it seems not to search well although the method works well when searching for a course (it gives in which faculty the course is and in which department). When the program is executed it gives us the message ("name" doesn't exist in this database) which indicates that cmp is still set to 0.

```
Program Liked_lists_database;
Type
Node = ^T;
T = record
    age : string;
    next, link : Node;
    end;
Var
Head, Tail, Last, tmp, tmp2, tmp3, tmp4, tmp5 : Node;
y : string;
cmp : integer;

Begin

  writeln('[+] Create your database [+]');
  writeln;
 Repeat
      write('Enter the name of the faculty : ');
    readln(j);
    if (j='exit') then break;
    if (Head = nil) then
    Begin
        new(Head);
        Tail := Head;
    End
    Else
    Begin
    new(Tail^.next);
    Tail := Tail^.next;
    End;
    Tail^.age := j;
    Tail^.next := nil;
        
        Repeat
            Write('Enter the name of the department : ');
            Readln(j);
            if (j='exit') then break;

            if (Tail^.link=Nil) Then
            Begin
                new(Tail^.link);
                Last := Tail^.link;
            End
            Else
            Begin
                new(Last^.next);
                Last := Last^.next;
            End;
            Last^.age := j;
            Last^.next := Nil;

            Repeat
            Write('Enter the name of the course : ');
            Readln(j);
            if (j='exit') then break;

            if (Tail^.link^.link=Nil) Then
            Begin
                new(Tail^.link^.link);
                Last := Tail^.link^.link;
            End
            Else
            Begin
                new(Last^.next);
                Last := Last^.next;
            End;
            Last^.age := j;
            Last^.next := Nil;

            Repeat
            Write('Enter the grade : ');
            Readln(j);
            if (j='exit') then break;

            if (Tail^.link^.link^.link=Nil) Then
            Begin
                new(Tail^.link^.link^.link);
                Last := Tail^.link^.link^.link;
            End
            Else
            Begin
                new(Last^.next);
                Last := Last^.next;
            End;
            Last^.age := j;
            Last^.next := Nil;

            Repeat
            Write('Enter the name of the student : ');
            Readln(j);
            if (j='exit') then break;

            if (Tail^.link^.link^.link^.link=Nil) Then
            Begin
                new(Tail^.link^.link^.link^.link);
                Last := Tail^.link^.link^.link^.link;
            End
            Else
            Begin
                new(Last^.next);
                Last := Last^.next;
            End;
            Last^.age := j;
            Last^.next := Nil;
        Until false;
        
        Until false;
        
        Until false;
        
        Until false;
        
Until false;
  
writeln;
writeln('...The database has been created successfully!');

// Search for a student
writeln('[+] Search for a student');
write('Enter the name of the student to Search for : ');
readln(y);
tmp := Head;
cmp := 0;
if (cmp=0) then
    While (tmp^.next<>Nil) Do
    Begin
        tmp2 := tmp^.link;
        While (tmp2^.next<>Nil) Do
        Begin
            tmp3 := tmp2^.link;
            While (tmp3^.next<>Nil) Do
            Begin
                tmp4 := tmp3^.link;
                While  (tmp4^.next<>Nil) Do
                Begin
                    tmp5 := tmp4^.link;
                    While (tmp5^.next<>Nil) Do
                    Begin
                        if (tmp5^.age=y) then
                            cmp := cmp + 1;
                        tmp5 := tmp5^.next;
                    End;
                    if (cmp>0) then
                        tmp4^.next := Nil
                    Else
                        tmp4 := tmp4^.next;
                End;
                if (cmp>0) then
                    tmp3^.next := Nil
                Else
                    tmp3 := tmp3^.next;
            End;
            if (cmp>0) then
                tmp2^.next := Nil
                Else
                    tmp2 := tmp2^.next;
        End;
        if (cmp>0) then
            tmp^.next := Nil
            Else
                tmp := tmp^.next;
    End;
if (cmp>0) then
Begin
writeln('Name : ',y);
writeln('Faculty : ', tmp^.age);
writeln('Department : ', tmp2^.age);
writeln('Speciality : ', tmp3^.age);
writeln('Grade : ', tmp4^.age);
End
Else
writeln(y, ' does not exist in this database');
  
End.
```

EDIT : the problem was with the implementation of the multilevel linked list and the searching algorithm

```
Program Liked_lists_database;
Type
Node = ^T;
T = record
    age : string;
    next, link : Node;
    end;
Var
Head, Tail, tmp, Last : Node;
j: string;
num : integer;

Procedure searchCourse;
Var
cmp : integer;
y : string;
tmp, tmp2, tmp3 : Node;
Begin
writeln('[+] Search for a course');
write('Enter the name of the course to Search for : ');
readln(y);
tmp := Head;
cmp := 0;

if (tmp^.next=Nil) Then
    new(tmp^.next);
While (tmp^.next<>Nil) Do
Begin
    tmp2 := tmp^.link;
    if (tmp2^.next=Nil) Then
        new(tmp2^.next);
    While (tmp2^.next<>Nil) Do
    Begin
        tmp3 := tmp2^.link;
        While (tmp3<>Nil) Do
        Begin
            if (tmp3^.age=y) Then
            Begin
                writeln('[', y, '] is found in faculty of [ ', tmp^.age, ']', ' department of [', tmp2^.age, ']');
                cmp := 1;
            End;
            tmp3 := tmp3^.next;
        End;
        if (cmp=0) Then
        Begin
            tmp2 := tmp2^.next;
            if (tmp2^.next=Nil) Then
            new(tmp2^.next);
        End
        Else
            tmp2^.next := Nil;
    End;
    if (cmp=0) Then
        Begin
            tmp := tmp^.next;
            if (tmp^.next=Nil) Then
            new(tmp^.next);
        End
        Else
            tmp^.next := Nil;
End;           

if (cmp=0) Then
    writeln ('[', y, '] : there is no such course');

End;

Begin
    // Fillin in the database
  writeln('[+] Create your database [+]');
  writeln;

        Repeat
          write('Enter the name of the faculty : ');
        readln(j);
        if (j='exit') then break;
        if (Head = nil) then
        Begin
            new(Head);
            Tail := Head;
        End
        Else
        Begin
        new(Tail^.next);
        Tail := Tail^.next;
        End;
        Tail^.age := j;
        Tail^.next := nil;
            
            Repeat
                Write('Enter the name of the department : ');
                Readln(j);
                if (j='exit') then break;

                if (Tail^.link=Nil) Then
                Begin
                    new(Tail^.link);
                    Last := Tail^.link;
                End
                Else
                Begin
                    new(Last^.next);
                    Last := Last^.next;
                End;
                Last^.age := j;
                Last^.next := Nil;

                Repeat
                Write('Enter the name of the course : ');
                Readln(j);
                if (j='exit') then break;

                if (Tail^.link^.link=Nil) Then
                Begin
                    new(Tail^.link^.link);
                    Last := Tail^.link^.link;
                End
                Else
                Begin
                    new(Last^.next);
                    Last := Last^.next;
                End;
                Last^.age := j;
                Last^.next := Nil;

                Repeat
                Write('Enter the grade : ');
                Readln(j);
                if (j='exit') then break;

                if (Tail^.link^.link^.link=Nil) Then
                Begin
                    new(Tail^.link^.link^.link);
                    Last := Tail^.link^.link^.link;
                End
                Else
                Begin
                    new(Last^.next);
                    Last := Last^.next;
                End;
                Last^.age := j;
                Last^.next := Nil;

                Repeat
                Write('Enter the name of the student : ');
                Readln(j);
                if (j='exit') then break;

                if (Tail^.link^.link^.link^.link=Nil) Then
                Begin
                    new(Tail^.link^.link^.link^.link);
                    Last := Tail^.link^.link^.link^.link;
                End
                Else
                Begin
                    new(Last^.next);
                    Last := Last^.next;
                End;
                Last^.age := j;
                Last^.next := Nil;
            Until false;
            
            Until false;
            
            Until false;
            
            Until false;
            
    Until false;

writeln;
writeln('...The database has been created successfully!');

searchCourse;

Readln;
End.
```

Comment: This is something you should be able to figure out with a small set of nodes. Use the debugger and set a breakpoint on the if after "Enter the name of the student". Run the app until you hit that breakpoint, and then start stepping through the code. The first thing you should figure out is that when you write `cmp := 0;` and then immediately write `if cmp = 0`, your if will **always** be true because you've just set `cmp := 0` on the preceeding line - either the assignment is a mistake or you don't need the two lines at all because you want the code inside the `if` to run every single time.

Comment: Also, you've got a lot wrong in your code. What's with `Head1, Head2, Head3, Head4, Head6`? the entire point of a linked list is that you only need one variable, `Curr`. `Prev` and `Next` can be read from that node. You need one more variable to use to add or insert. You don't need two dozen variables to point at each node along the way.

Comment: Hi Ken, thank you for responding. I'm new to multilevel linked lists, I just read an article about how they look like and implemented this by myself. My view was that if this list has 5 levels (like in this case) I'll need to create five linked lists each with its head pointer. And concerning the variable cmp, I just  made that condition to make  sure if cmp is not equal to zero which means we found the student the while loop won't work (which won't work without the condition too cause we said if cmp>0 then tmp^.next :=  Nil).

Comment: You are going about this in completely the wrong way, imo.  Please post a link to the article you mentioned.

Comment: @MartynA the article I read was just plain text of what multilevel linked lists are and how the look like, no sample code was included, so the problem is with creating the database? am I filling it the wrong way?

Comment: I worked this way, with two pointers for each node, https://www.ritambhara.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Screen-Shot-2018-06-11-at-2.31.18-PM.png

Comment: *concerning the variable cmp, I just made that condition to make sure if cmp is not equal to zero * Read again what I wrote. **cmp will ALWAYS be zero, because you SET IT TO ZERO with `cmp := 0;` just before the if**. **IT WILL ALWAYS BE ZERO the way your code is written.** I explained why your code is **totally wrong** in my last comment, in detail. You should read it again.

Comment: I don't need too many variables, that's true but that doesn't make my code wrong, it creates the lists correctly

Comment: I spotted the problem, the searching algorithm is correct but the multilevel linked list isn't implemented correctly.. But I couldn't make any progress with it

Comment: All the departments are created inside the first faculty

Comment: @Ken White, I arrived at at a solution for the list. Now it's working properly but I found out that the searching procedure doesn't return a correct value...Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes. Use the debugger to step through the code to find out why it's not returning the correct value. You need to learn to use the debugger - it is the most powerful tool you can have in your programming toolbox, and it's never too early to start learning how to use it.

Comment: @Ken White, I never used it but I'll make sure to take it up as a new essential skill...thanks for your help, most appreciated!

Comment: Can you please lead me to how to use the debugger with pascal, i made a search online and I found that I-pascal is a good plugin but Intellij IDEA requires a fairly good computer, can I denug with Pascal XE? If there is a good software please tell me. Thanks

Comment: "Can you please lead me to how .."  Well, if you are serious about learning to program, you need to get yourself a Pascal implementation with a decent debugger.  Far and away the best is in Delphi and there is a free version available - the [Community Edition](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/starter?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=Brand_-_Exact&gclid=CjwKCAjwm7mEBhBsEiwA_of-TDhXGevOrqL4p6pydp-stpH2l5dXGhPvHIJyLEHfE3MCTedvA4CxABoCe54QAvD_BwE).  The best alternative to that is [Lazarus](https://www.lazarus-ide.org/index.php?page=downloads) for the FPC compiler.

Comment: @MartynA Thank you so much, I got Lazarus with FPC and it's awesome, I'm getting more familiar with the debugger. I read some articles about Delphi and how its syntax is just like Pascal. So, is it easy to move on from Pascal to Delphi as it offers more. And do you think Delphi is still worth learning and working with nowadays? Especially for networking because I'm interested in that field and I thought why wasting my time learning another language with a completely different syntax while Delphi is available.